How to tie a vendor module into an Android 14 build
I'm currently trying to write a simple hello world vendor module for android 14 to run on the cuttlefish emulator but I can't figure out how to tie it into the build properly.
Documentation on how exactly to write a vendor module for use with a GKI leaves something to be desired.
I wrote the Android.bp and the module source under the folder vendor/avtest/ (source below). Then I added the module to the BoardConfig.mk in the variable BOARD_VENDOR_KERNEL_MODULES. This doesn't seem to work, so any help figuring it out would be awesome.
The first error I get is confusing because there is no PHONY targets in my makefile:
out/soong/Android-aosp_cf_x86_64_phone.mk was modified, regenerating...
[100% 152/152] writing legacy Make module rules ...
FAILED:
build/make/core/Makefile:699: error: real file "out/target/product/vsoc_x86_64/obj/PACKAGING/depmod_vendor_stripped_intermediates/hello.ko" depends on PHONY target "hello.ko"
09:59:03 ckati failed with: exit status 1

If I change the BOARD_VENDOR_KERNEL_MODULES from hello.ko to vendor/avtest/hello.ko I get the follow error that suggests that it's not even attempting to compile my module:
device/google/cuttlefish/vsoc_x86_64/BoardConfig.mk was modified, regenerating...
FAILED: ninja: 'vendor/avtest/hello.ko', needed by 'out/target/product/vsoc_x86_64/obj/PACKAGING/depmod_vendor_stripped_intermediates/hello.ko', missing and no known rule to make it
09:38:18 ninja failed with: exit status 1

To get where I am, I cloned and built android 14 android-14.0.0_r29. I confirmed that cuttlefish will build and run.
mkdir <aosp>
cd <aosp>
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-14.0.0_r29 --current-branch --depth=1
repo sync -c -j8 --no-tags --no-clone-bundle
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_cf_x86_64_phone-ap1a-userdebug
make

Then I added the vendor module under <aosp>/vendor/avtest/
hello.c:
#include <linux/module.h>    // included for all kernel modules
#include <linux/kernel.h>    // included for KERN_INFO
#include <linux/init.h>      // included for __init and __exit macros

static int __init hello_init(void) {
    printk(KERN_ERR "hello world init\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_exit(void) {
    printk(KERN_ERR "hello world exit\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);

MODULE_AUTHOR("Alex");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("helloworld");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_VERSION("0.01");

Android.bp:
cc_binary {
    name: "hello",
    srcs: ["hello.c"],
    vendor: true,
}

and finally added it to the build in <aosp>/device/google/cuttlefish/vsoc_x86_64/BoardConfig.mk
BOARD_VNDK_VERSION := current
BOARD_VENDOR_KERNEL_MODULES += hello.ko

I also have a Makefile and a Kbuild, but neither of those get picked up by the build system either (putting giberish in them doesn't throw any errors). I'm not sure if they are necessary when using an Android.bp instead of a Android.mk, and $(KDIR) doesn't get populated by the lunch command anyways.
Makefile:
default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD clean $(KBUILD_OPTIONS)

Kbuild:
obj-m += hello.o

